# How am I supposed to control the flow of my deployments?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

What are the new pipeline best practices?

Documentation is all over the place and seriously incomplete.

Environments that allows you to use Gates and Checks like a year back was flagged to soon support AppServices, that part has been removed.

Environments supported "You dont have to specify a resource now" which meant I could do it through code has now been replaced by "The Kubernetes resource and virtual machine resource types are currently supported."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops#environment-resources

The Manual Intervention Task that was supposed to act as a gate turned out after 6 months wait to be a glorified "Sleep" which now also is only available for servers and NOT Microsoft Hosted Agents.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-intervention?view=azure-devops#demands

When the best practice is pushed as to have one pipeline to run validation, tests, build, deploy to dev, test and prod you need the darn control over the release flow and how to achieve this is nowhere to be found.

What is the plan here? How do I achieve these things? Do I break best practice and make multiple pipelines? Do I build myself into a corner by using the legacy release pipelines? Why hasnt the release pipelien functionality and GUI been ported to YAML yet?

The design and workflow becomes infuriating and unnecessarily complex and annoying to say the least.

I might have found a workaround: https://ochzhen.com/blog/manual-trigger-in-yaml-azure-pipelines

Anyone able to help explain or point me in the direction of the best practices of the new Azure Pipelines?

Comment: I think you need to come up with a specific question in your mind instead of asking for 'best practices'

Comment: @ssilas777
Well shouldn't there be documentation covering the bases of a system from end to end? I'm not sure how I should formulate a more specific question. Most parts of the DevOps environment are well documentet, a lot of places are not. But Ive been working with this for 1,5 years now and there still isnt a single example of how Microsoft thinks that you're actually supposed to be working in their product.

Documentation tells you "You can do this" but no example of "You should do this"

Comment: @ssilas777
I just want a link to where the best practices of how I should set everything up so I don't have to build myself into a corner everywhere.

Where is the line drawn between Self Hosted and Microsoft Hosted agents? Why isnt the documentation showing what works on what platform? I mean help me out here.

The question is pretty specific btw, how do I control the flow of my deployments?
How do I stop things from going from dev -> test -> prod without breaking the percieved best practice of multi-staged-pipelines.

The solutions are there on Server, but not Hosted agents.

Answer (score 0):

For isolating different environments in a pipeline we are using variable and conditions like this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

```
# Special Run Description Variables
- name: IsPullRequest
  value: ${{ or(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'), eq(parameters.ForcePullRequest, true)) }}
   
- name: IsCIRun
  value: ${{ or(and(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'), in(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI', 'BatchedCI')), eq(parameters.DeployCI, true)) }}

- name: IsUatRun
  value: ${{ or(and(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main'), in(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI', 'BatchedCI')), eq(parameters.DeployUat, true)) }}
```

Not sure if this answer your question, but hope this can be a good place to start

Comment: Thank you @ssilas777, I found one of these blogs earlier that helped me achieve what I needed.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml
Doesnt list the Manual version, but I did manage to find here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services